# How to conditionally fallback to base mapping on inheritance maps?

Tags: inheritance, mapping, automapper, fallback

Given that I have a property mapping for a derived class and a mapping for a base class targetting the same property, how can I tell AutoMapper to fallback to the base mapping conditionally?

Say I need the following mapping between `Exception` class hierarchy and `MyModel`, where `MyModel` is as follows:

```
class MyModel
{
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on the type of exception and its properties, I want different messages to be output. A manual mapping logic would look somewhat like this:

```
switch (exception)
{
    case SqlException sqlEx when sqlEx.Number = 53:
        return new MyModel { Message = "Db conn issue" };

    case Exception e when e.Message == null:
        return new MyModel { Message = "Default message" };

    default:
        return new MyModel { Message = exception.Message };       
}
```

I want to transport that logic into an AutoMapper profile.

This is what I tried:

```
CreateMap<Exception, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Message, opt => 
    {
        opt.MapFrom(ex => ex.Message);
        opt.NullSubstitute("Default message");
    }
    .Include<SqlException, MyModel>();

CreateMap<SqlException, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Message, opt => 
    {
        opt.Condition(ex => ex.Number == 53);
        opt.UseValue("Db issue");
    };
```

Whenever I try to map an `SqlException` that does not have `Number == 53`, it skips the mapping completely and returns `null`. I wanted it to fallback to the base mapping specification in this case and return whatever would be valid for the `Exception` case.

Is there a mechanism to support this scenario? If not, can you suggest an alternative mapping strategy that would result in the wanted mapping?

Comment: You don't need the MapFrom in the base mapping. Just use a resolver for the derived map.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but in that case I'd need to have explicit type checks inside the resolve function right? I'd like to avoid those if possible. I'd like to know if using inheritance mapping is possible here first, and only then fallback to `ResolveUsing`.

Comment: A resolver in the derived mapping, the source of that mapping is already SqlException.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, if I configure a resolver on the `SqlException` mapping for `Message` won't that still override the default values on the `Exception` mapping? Please keep in mind that I need this mapping to be generic (i.e. I want to be able to map from any exception type). If I use a resolver on the more specific mapping, I'll have to replicate the default message value again there, which is less than ideal.

Comment: No, you override just the message, the rest are inherited.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but if I override the message mapping, I'll have to duplicate the default again in case the `Number` is different than 53 right? If not, can you post an answer with what you have in mind?

Comment: ```opt.MapFrom(ex =>ex.Number == 53 ? "Db error." : ex.Message);```

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu this does not leverage the `NullSubstitute` on the original mapping.

Comment: As I've already said, that's unrelated, it's inherited.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, can you post an answer with your proposal here? I still don't see how it would work without code duplication.

Comment: @aaron not really. See my comment on the answer below. I can certainly "solve the business case", but not without either 1: replicating code across mappers, or 2: not using inheritance mapping in the first place. Both options are far from ideal IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateMap<Exception, MyModel>()
      .ForMember(m => m.Message, opt => opt.NullSubstitute("Default message"))
      .Include<SqlException, MyModel>();

CreateMap<SqlException, MyModel>().ForMember(m => m.Message, 
      opt => opt.MapFrom(ex =>ex.Number == 53 ? "Db error." : ex.Message));
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, as you still need to have `ex.Message` on the `SqlException` mapping, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid. It also doesn't leverage `NullSubstitute` from the original mapping, and thus is wrong. I wanted a solution that cleanly mapped the same `Message` property without code duplication, that is, in a way as to reuse the base mapping from inside the specific mapping.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how inheritance works with AM. So, either try to do it the AM way, or forget about AM and do it by hand or smth.

Comment: I've used inheritance mapping quite extensively in the past with AutoMapper, but never hit a case where I needed different mapping strategies for the same property in an inheritance hierarchy. Maybe the answer to the "How to conditionally fallback to base mapping on inheritance maps?" question is just "you can't do it"? I just wanted to make sure it wasn't possible. The AM API is crazy extensive and not very intuitive sometimes. If I can confirm that it's not possible, I'd consider adding a feature request on their Github myself.